# mod_rewrite creates 301 instead of transparent redirection if folder exists

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

i'm having a small problem here.
I'm using a simple rule to redirect all requests to a script, excepts some folders with static content :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(templates|css|js|uploads)/(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Most of the time, the redirection is good and transparent.
But if the folder matching the URL exists and if i don't put the last "/", i will have a 301 redirect.

Examples : (the folder gallery doesn't exists but mods does)

- ht*p://localhost/test/gallery/ -> OK
- ht*p://localhost/test/mods/ -> OK
- ht*p://localhost/test/mods -> 301 redirection to ht*p://localhost/test/mods/?url=mods

I have this problem on all apache2 servers (tested Fedora, Debian, Windows).

Someone knows how to solve this ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the [`DirectorySlash`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash) directive, which will perform the external redirection after your rewrite is performed, which has the unintended consequence of taking your added query string with it.

You can turn `DirectorySlash` off, but it's not recommended for the reasons described in the documentation. The preferred option in this case is probably to just perform `mod_dir`'s work for it, redirecting to the appropriate slash-terminated URL before performing your rules. Something like this above your existing rule should work:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteRule ^.*$ /$0/ [R=301,L]
```